# Strange method behavior when called from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I have a button that changes the view controller, all views are within a Navigation controller.

When I transition it using the Button I made everything works perfectly

```
- (IBAction)new:(id)sender {


UIViewController *nextView = (UIViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView1"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];

}
```

However when I use the exact same code in a method I call from another class it doesn't work! I get the "HERE" I printed out in the log so I know it is being called correctly. Is it possible that the self is not working because I call it from another class? As I said it's the exact same code in both places.

```
-(void)nextpage
{
NSLog(@"HERE");

UIViewController *nextView = (UIViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView1"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: So, the question is whether you other class (a) is a view controller; (b) is a view controller in a navigation controller (not, for example, a child controller within another view controller, that is within a navigation controller. I'd try logging `self.navigationController` where you're currently logging `HERE` and make sure the navigation controller is present and accounted for.

Comment: I'm calling it from a view controller embedded in a navigation controller. I'm not getting why it would work from the button but not the call.

Comment: Ok. Just logged it. When it comes from the button it says <UINavigationController: 0xac54ed0> and when it comes from the call it says (null)

Comment: very good. Quite simply, your problem is not in the code you've shared with us, but somewhere in the code that called `next`. E.g. Did you do modal to get to that controller? It's got to be something like that. Track back and I'm sure you'll find it. For example, log it in `viewDidLoad` of second controller, see if it's `nil` there, too, or not. It will be slow going, but you'll figure it out. No way we can help without a lot more info about how you got to your second controller...

Comment: Thanks. I call it from a subview on the first view controller. I have script in there that calls this method. I'll look into it more. What do you think I should log in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that by replacing the self with the class I can get this working. Whenever I list my classname it doesn't work and I get errors. How do I replace self with my view controller class

Comment: You don't want to replace `self` with your current controller class, but rather with the particular instance object that is the current view controller within the navigation controller. In terms of how you get that, it depends entirely upon what this secondary object is (a `UIView` subclass? a `UIViewController`? if a view controller, did you do the `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentController` calls?) But the basic idea is that you have to keep track of the pointer to that first view controller instance, and use that when calling `pushViewController` call.

Comment: I got it working by creating a method that returned the current navigation controller on viewdidload and stored it as a variable. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. You were right about the problem